# Full width button material dialogs

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-5.0-lollipop, android-dialog

I am trying to find an example code to implement a material dialog with full width buttons as shown in the screenshot below.

Can someone help by sharing example code on how to replicate this design?
[image]

Comment: See this page [Here](https://github.com/lewisjdeane/L-Dialogs)

Answer (score 7):

You could achieve that with using ONLY AppCompat, check my workaround:

**Code**

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.StackedAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dignissim purus eget gravida mollis. Integer in auctor turpis. Morbi auctor, diam eget vestibulum congue, quam arcu pulvinar dui, blandit egestas erat enim non ligula." +
            " Nunc quis laoreet libero. Aliquam consectetur nibh eu arcu eleifend efficitur.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Positive Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Neutral Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
        try{
            final Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) button.getParent();
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //ignore it
        }
```

**Style**

```
<style name="StackedAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/StackedButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="StackedButtonBarButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
</style>
```

**Result**

[image: Stacked Alert Dialog]

Comment: This is not a very good idea. Firstly, there is an assumption of the layout of dialog, which is internal and could change. Secondly, the appCompat's implementation shows that alertDialog.getButton returns null because the buttons are set only on the show() function, by which time this logic won't affect the dialog layout

Comment: Not very good, is that android sdk, not provide api to modify alert dialog according the material guidelines. Of course internal implementation could be changed, but if you will update appcompat version, you need to check that dialog will work fine after the update - but this is workaround and it could have limitations.

Comment: I am using appcompat v24.0.0.0, seems like it automatically stack the buttons vertically when the text are long.

Comment: @Bruce Yes seems that support of stack buttons in alert dialog were included into one of latest version of appcompat

Comment: I agree that it is risky modifying an internal layout.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's how i am doing in my app using ONLY AppCompat library**
You can any number of options

```
String[] mOptionsArray = new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2"};
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Cool! title");
    builder.setMessage("Cool! message");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_view, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getContext(),
            R.layout.dialog_list_item,
            R.id.button,
            mOptionsArray
    ));
    listView.setDivider(null);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemClickListener);
    builder.setView(view);

    return builder.create();
}
```

**dialog_list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />
```

**dialog_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

Ref: http://www.materialdoc.com/flat-button/, https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs, https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-style

[image: Dialog with stacked full-width buttons]

Answer (score 0):

It is automatic if buttons have long message text.

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage(R.string.lorem_inpsum)
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.long_positive), null)
                .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.long_negative), null)
                .show();
```

[image]